# knitr and biblatex

Tags: r, pdftex, knitr, biblatex

I'd like to create a PDF report with `knitr` with `LaTeX`-code in `RStudio` with `biblatex` for citations. However, the in-text-citations are always undefined and no bibliography is printed. The same bibliography works perfectly with a pure `.tex`-document stored in the same folder and containing the same citations, same path to the `.bib`-file etc. However, as for all references (also with `hyperref`) I have to compile twice. I thought this might be the problem with `knitr` (that the compilation is run only once), but the `hyperref`-references to figures work well. Any idea what might go wrong with the bibliography when using `knitr` and how I can solve the problem?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, maxnames=1, bibencoding=utf8, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{ZoteroOutput.bib}

\begin{document}

According to the literature \parencite{gonzalez2003} we can assume...

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

From the `log`-file:

```
Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                mwe
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

Comment: Show us a reproducible example. Do you have `use texi2dvi` enabled? http://rstudio.org/docs/using/customizing

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I added an MWE. In the `Rstudio` options, I can only find `Invoke compiler via texi2dvi script`. I have now enabled it, but this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: The message seems to be very explicit. As a temp fix, you can run pdflatex on that .tex file again (outside Rstudio).

Comment: @RomanLuštrik So there is no way to get it with one click in `knitr`/`RStudio`? That's a bit disappointing. How does it create the within-text-figure references then? As far as I know, they also need a 2nd compilation.

Comment: Try running the latex output file once in miktex or what ever after ward.  For me after I run it once in miktex the citations show up using Rstudio.  I think this is because the encessary files are created by miktex and then can be run later when using R studio.

Comment: I am doing a similar thing to this but I want to use a filepath to my bibtex database something like... \bibliography{my folder/subfolder/ZoteroOutput.bib} but this doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

RStudio allows you to use a [custom LaTeX program](http://www.rstudio.org/docs/authoring/latex_program?version=0.97.54&mode=desktop) with that

- you can set up a script that does the proper processing
- there are automatic solutions for this, e.g. [`latexmk`](http://ctan.tug.org/tex-archive/support/latexmk/), like so: `Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PDFLATEX = "/Library/TeX/texbin/latexmk")` (or whatever you path may be)

Another option is that RStudio allows to specify build tools for a project. This may be

- either a Makefile
- or again a custom script

In addition, you may want to tell the RStudio developers about the need to have a bibliography in Sweave documents. You can tell them that I'd need it, too :-)

Comment: Have you managed to get that to work?

Comment: Here's one way to make it work for a document that has biber + biblatex + XeLaTeX + embedded R in it: `mkdoc <- function(fname){ require(knitr); res <- knit(fname); if (!is.null(res)) { system2('latexmk', args=c('-xelatex', res)) } }` Then call `mkdoc('myfile.Rnw')` instead of pressing the compile button. After a few passes it generates `myfile.pdf`. Having this sort of thing built into RStudio would indeed be nicer.

Comment: It might be a bit more robust to do `Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PDFLATEX = Sys.which("latexmk"))`.

Answer (score 6):

It is actually really easy to produce a PDF with `knitr` with `LaTeX`-code in `RStudio` with `biblatex` for citations.

You have to use the option `bib_engine = "biber"` from the package `tinytex::latexmk` within `knitr::knit2pdf`.

Just like here: `knitr::knit2pdf(file.Rnw, bib_engine = "biber")`

Comment: This works for me, I wonder if there is a way to make make it permanent so you can use the RStudio render button

Answer (score 5):

I think that the problem is in your `backend`, because Rstudio uses `texi2dvi` to write pdf and then it does not know about `biber`.

Try to change:

`\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}`

with

`\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}`

in the preamble.

Normally this work.

Comment: That seems to work for the built in biblatex styles but unfortunately the APA package now requires biber, so that can't be made to work this way.

Answer (score 5):

Even though the question was asked long ago, any reader in the future might find this useful:

http://texblog.org/2013/08/20/rknitr-automatic-bibliography-generation-with-biblatex-in-rstudio/

Comment: This worked for me, and is the most clean solution I was looking for.

<<Setup, eval=T, echo=FALSE, include = FALSE, results='hide'>>=
setwd('myworkingdirectory')
Sys.setenv(TEXINPUTS=getwd(),
           BIBINPUTS=getwd(),
           BSTINPUTS=getwd())
@
`

Answer (score 4):

This kinda works when I press the compile button twice. It is just an ugly system call to `biber`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Doe,author={John Doe},title={Title}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

Test \cite{Doe}

\printbibliography
\end{document}

<<biber>>=
system(paste("biber", sub("\\.Rnw$", "", current_input())))
@
```

Comment: this is the best hack-fix that I got to work.

Answer (score 0):

The standard procedure for getting citations to work properly is that you have to:

1) Run LaTeX

2) Run BibTex

3) Run LaTeX

4) Run LaTeX

One option is to use the command texify, others use a makefile. I am not entirely sure about what `knitr` runs, but probably it does not run the sequence enough. Personally, I use Emacs with ESS, combined with AuCTeX; it really works well for me.

P.S. I don't think you need to specify that it's a `.bib` file.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, which has no standard solution yet which I know of. (If I am wrong I would be pleased to be pointed to a better solution.)

I got the following to work with **rstudio, knitr, biblatex, and biber**. It probably only works for linux, but could possibly be adapted to other systems.

1. create a wrapper file with the following content:

`#!/usr/bin/bash
/usr/bin/latexmk -pv- -quiet -pdf -xelatex $@`

Let's assume, you called the file `~/bin/rstudiolatex.sh`. Make sure to use the correct path to `bash` which might be `/bin/bash` on your machine. The command line options to latexmk could be shortened I guess.

2. Make the file (`~/bin/rstudiolatex`) executable.
3. add the following line to the R startup `~/.Rprofile`:

`Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PDFLATEX = "/your/path/to/rstudiolatex.sh")`

Make sure to insert your proper path to `rstudiolatex.sh`.