# How to re-run Bibtex on the file(s) - RSweave; KnitR

Tags: biblatex, knitr, sweave, markdown, rnw

I have a document called Code.Rnw where I write my document in and I'm using Sweave and Knitr to compile it.

For my bibliography I use biblatex. My setting is the following:

```
\usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear, citestyle=authoryear, backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}
\bibliography{bib}
```

Unfortunately my whole header is very long so I won't post it.

Until now the bibliography file (bib.bib) was printed in the PDF output without any problems but suddenly the following error occured:

```
Please (re)run Bibtex on the file(s):(biblatex) Code(biblatex) and rerun Latex afterwards.
```

Actually I don't have a clue how to (re)run Bibtex especially in the environment with Sweave and KnitR. I can't run my bib file or any other file seperatly; except for my main Rnw (Code.Rnw) file of course. How do I deal with the situation?

Thanks

Comment: For anyone having a similar problem. I found, that my Code.BBL file wasn't updating anymore when I compiled the document. For now the solution is the following: Update the bibliography (in my case bib.bib) and save it. Delete the Code.BBL file (yours will have the name of your Rnw document) and then compile the Code.Rnw (or whatever your main document is named) 2 times. This creates a PDF output for me.

Comment: Please consider adding your work-around as an answer so others can benefit from it as well. Contents in the comments is not always read by people who are looking for an answer.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71565/35864

Answer (score 2):

For anyone having a similar problem. I found, that my *Code.BBL* file wasn't updating anymore when I compiled the document. For now the solution is the following: Update the bibliography file (in my case *bib.bib*) and save it. Delete the *Code.BBL* file (yours will have the name of your Rnw document) and then compile the *Code.Rnw* (or whatever your main document is named) 2 times. This creates a PDF output for me.