# Embedding R (kable) results in LaTeX

Tags: r, knitr, rnw

Apology at first if this question has been asked or the sample is not reproducible. I'm totally new to LaTex and happy to take any advice.

I am working on my thesis on a `.tex` LaTex template given by the university, and I just saved it as a `.rnw` file since I would like to include some R results. Before I added code, the file can knitr well and generate a pdf.

```
\documentclass[master,tocprelim]{cornell}
\usepackage{graphicx,pstricks}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{moreverb}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{hangcaption}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{palatino}
\graphicspath{ {figures/} }

\begin{document}

He said it is cool\cite{tkh1998}. 

<<code, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE>>=
library(kableExtra)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
data = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20, 10, 2), ncol=4))
kable(data, 'latex', caption = 'Time series Errors', 
        longtable = T, booktabs = T) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "hold_position", "repeat_header"))
@

\appendix

%\bibliography{LR}

\end{document}
```

(I don't know how to include reference in the `.rnw` file, but my `.bib` file include this citation:

```
@ARTICLE{tkh1998, 
author={ {Tin Kam Ho}}, 
journal={IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence}, 
title={The random subspace method for constructing decision forests}, 
year={1998}, 
volume={20}, 
number={8}, 
pages={832-844}, 
keywords={pattern classification;trees (mathematics);decision theory;random processes;learning (artificial intelligence);random subspace method;decision forests;decision trees;overfitting;maximum accuracy;decision tree based classifier;generalization accuracy;feature vector;classification accuracy;Decision trees;Classification tree analysis;Training data;Clustering algorithms;Tin;Stochastic systems;Binary trees;Support vector machines;Support vector machine classification}, 
doi={10.1109/34.709601}, 
ISSN={0162-8828}, 
month={Aug},}
```

However, after I added:

```
<<code, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE>>=
library(kableExtra)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
data = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20, 10, 2), ncol=4))
kable(data, 'latex', caption = 'Time series Errors', 
        longtable = T, booktabs = T) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "hold_position", "repeat_header"))
@
```

This file cannot be knitr anymore. It produced errors including "citation `tkh1998` undefined on input line 86" (I don't even have line 86!!), "Incompatible color definition on input line 89", "Undefined control sequence".

I appreciate any suggestion about integrating LaTeX output and R results together (especially KableExtra outputs), shall I mainly write in `.tex` or `.rnw`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE. This answer suggests that you use the `biblatex` package and `biber` to produce your citations and bibliography. The answer then assumes you are using `RStudio` as your editor and to compile your `.Rnw` file.

Executing `biber` from within RStudio was answered here: [How to insert references and bibliography into a .Rnw file produce with RStudio R Sweave and knitr?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/481308/)

You need to add this code chunk:

```
<<biber, eval= TRUE, include= FALSE, cache= FALSE, echo= FALSE>>=
system (paste ("biber", sub ("\\.Rnw$", "", current_input())))
@
```

This will call `biber` to produce the `.bbl` file required for producing a bibliography. Note that `RStudio` automatically deletes this file at the end of the compilation so you cannot see it.

Compile the `.Rnw` file twice to produce the citations and bibliography.

I removed packages not required for this MWE. However, since you have the `kable` option `booktabs = T` you will need to load the `booktabs` package with `\usepackage{booktabs}`. Another `kable` option used in the MWE is `striped`. This uses `\rowcolor` from the `xcolor` package, so you also need to load that as well. Finally, the table is not being set using the longtable environment, so write `longtable = F`. You need `longtable = T` when the table will span more than one page.

This is output:

[image]

This is the MWE;

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{tkh1998,
author={ {Tin Kam Ho}},
journal={IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence},
title={The random subspace method for constructing decision forests},
year={1998},
volume={20},
number={8},
pages={832-844},
keywords={pattern classification;trees (mathematics);decision theory;random processes;learning (artificial intelligence);random subspace method;decision forests;decision trees;overfitting;maximum accuracy;decision tree based classifier;generalization accuracy;feature vector;classification accuracy;Decision trees;Classification tree analysis;Training data;Clustering algorithms;Tin;Stochastic systems;Binary trees;Support vector machines;Support vector machine classification},
doi={10.1109/34.709601},
ISSN={0162-8828},
month={Aug},}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}         % reqired for booktabs=T
\usepackage[backend= biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}    % required for "striped"
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

He said it is cool\cite{tkh1998}.

<<code, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE>>=
library(kableExtra)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
data = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20, 10, 2), ncol=4))
kable(data, 'latex', caption = 'Time series Errors',
        longtable = F, booktabs = T) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "hold_position", "repeat_header"))
@

\appendix

<<biber, eval= TRUE, include= FALSE, cache= FALSE, echo= FALSE>>=
system (paste ("biber", sub ("\\.Rnw$", "", current_input())))
@

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Ross! Would it be possible to use an external `.bib` file for bibliography? For instance, `\bibliography{job}` where `job.bib` is located under the same folder as `.rnw` file. (When I made above changes on your basis, it generated an error saying `undefined control sequence`...

Comment: Rachel. This setup for the MWE uses `\begin{filecontents}` `\end{filecontents}` to make the example complete and portable. You can remove this part since you already have your `.bib` file. You can have any `*.bib` file in your working directory and just reference that file using `addbibresource{bibfilename.bib}`. The `undefined control sequence` indicates a command is not recognized. Was there additional information with that error to provide a clue about what command was not recognized? Can you compile the example exactly as posted, with just this one bibentry?

Comment: Hi Ross, never mind, I have a few packages out of date and now it worked out perfectly. Thanks so much!